# "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" when attempting function of np.meshgrid Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

Am trying to create a 3D plot in Python where I have an FFT on the XY plane and a parameter on the Z axis

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from scipy.signal import blackman

Nmax=64 # length of logistic series and no of FFT bins
 
w = blackman(Nmax) # blackman window for FFT

def fourier_of_logmap(k, r): # returns kth  element in spectrum for given r
    
    x_0 = 0.5
    x_n = x_0

    n_0 = 0
    n = n_0
    
    x_values = []
    
    while n < Nmax:
        
        y = r*x_n*(1-x_n)
            
        x_values.append(x_n)
            
        n = n + 1
        x_n = y

    fourier = np.log(abs(fft(w*x_values)))
    return fourier[k]

test = fourier_of_logmap(20,3.7) #test if function is working

k_values = np.linspace(0, Nmax-1, Nmax)
r_values = np.linspace(0,4,100)

K, R = np.meshgrid(k_values, r_values)

A = fourier_of_logmap(K, R)

'Plot 3d surface'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(K, R, A, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```

Testing the function with 'test' returns a float as desired. However when applied to (K, R) I get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". Yet when I replace fourier_of_logmap with a simple function like K + R it runs fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: Some place (you haven't shown where the error occurs) you try to assign a `sequence` (an array, list or tuple) to an slot of an array that can only take one element.  In other words, multiple values into one. You/we need to look at the full traceback to identify where this is happening, especially if it's deep within a function call.

Comment: What's the purpose of lines like `n_values = []`?

Comment: ahh yeah those lines were left behind from a previous version- have reformatted it and annotated it to better explain what i mean